# Flexslider stop at first slide after loop

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I am trying to get the Flexslider to make a full loop and then stop or pause once it gets back to the first slide. Here is my code so far:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: true, 
        slideshowSpeed: 5000,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        start: function(slider){
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: true, 
        slideshowSpeed: 5000,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        start: function(slider){
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
        },
        after: function (slider) {
            if ((slider.currentSlide + 1) == slider.count) {
                 slider.pause();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That made it pause at the 3rd slide, BUT I did get it to work by changing this line: 
slider.currentSlide == 0
So thank you!

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't understand properly your requirements. I hope that I a little bit help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this, it worked for me

$(window).load(function(){
    var loopCount = 0; 
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: true, 
        slideshowSpeed: 5000,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        start: function(slider){
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
        },
        after : function(slider){
           if(slider.currentSlide == 0 && loopCount == 1){
             slider.pause();
           }   
        },
        end : function(slider){
          loopCount++;  
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to pause at first slide after looping specific times. change var n value to loop as many time you wish.

```
var n = 2; 
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideshowSpeed: 5000,
    start: function(slider) {
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
    },
    after: function(slider) {
        if (slider.currentSlide == 0) { // is last slide
            n--;
            if(n==0) {
                slider.pause();
            }
        }
    }
});
```