# How to add class to Flexslider first slide?

Tags: jquery, list, overlay, flexslider

I want to put overlay to first slide only but Im not that good with jQuery.

It would be easy but I have plenty of flexsliders generated with pictures that user uploads - every slider is basically with different content and lenght and directly adding overlay with CSS is not an option.

Flexslider slides are just < li> elements that are sitting in < ul>. **How to add class to first < li>?**

Don't think that Im lazy, I searched plenty in Google and I don't even know where to start.

Best I could find that might be some kind of start is [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072307/flexslider-stop-at-first-slide-after-loop) stackoverflow question.

Comment: You should just do something like: $('.flexslider ul li:first-child').addClass('class-name');

If your flexsliders class is "flexslider"

Comment: That did the trick! So simple but so effective. Copy it as answer to my question and I'll mark it as solved. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just do something like:
$('.flexslider ul li:first-child').addClass('class-name');
If your flexsliders class is "flexslider"